# Flicker recording impress presentation with kazam

Tags: libreoffice, kazam

I use kazam to record libreoffice impress presentations but since moving to kubuntu on ubuntu 20.04 there is a flicker when the screen updates. I need to record the mouse because I am often demonstrating how to use impress to my students.

The flicker is not visible at recording time. Only on playback.

Example at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pssk0WVDIhM&feature=youtu.be

Libreoffice

Version: 6.4.6.2
Build ID: 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 5.4; UI render: default; VCL: kf5;
Locale: en-GB (en_GB.UTF-8); UI-Language: en-GB
Calc: threaded

Kazam
Kazam NCC-"80102"
1.4.5

NVIDEA 340 drivers

340-108

This used to work fine.

Any idea of fixes or alternates to kazam?

**Update and further question**

I have just installed simplescreenrecorder to see if it fixes the problem.

I'm definitely recording - the preview box is updating but despite recording a 2 minute clip I'm only getting a 262byte file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The initial problem was kazam. I switched to simplescreenrecorder and everything is fine.

The problem in the update is something to do with the audio. I switched audio off in SSR and the video is recording fine. It's a PITA to record the narration separately but I have a solution. If I find at solution to SSR not recording properly with the sound on I'll post it.

Comment: The default audio source in SSR was JACK. Changed it to PulseAudio and tadaa! All good.